# Ignite nodes for computing task but without data storage

Tags: java, ignite

I'm using Ignite for a mix of in-memory only and persistence data caches on several network servers.

Most nodes participate in task computing and cache access, but only some participate in data persistence on disk. Currently I'm controlling the data storage through NodeFilter that checks the attributes of those servers that shall store data on disk.
However, this still requires the nodes that shall not store data on disk to configure `persistenceEnabled=true`, which also requires these nodes to have a storagePath, walPath and walArchivePath which wouldn't actually be used.

Is there an easier to way to configure nodes for computing tasks but without data persistence storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start compute nodes as client nodes, then you can schedule computations on them using `ClusterGroup` (by default, compute is only sent to server nodes).

Comment: By default compute is only sent to client nodes? Is this a typo? I can read here that it runs on servers by default: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers#computing-on-clients-or-servers

Comment: Yes, I will fix.

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing this out, I didn't notice in the documentation that client nodes can participate in compute tasks.